# Specific cases of 528 Hz harmonics that appear in nature that are not wideband radiation or noise?

Tags: geophysics, geobiology

I was looking up something about the 528 Hz frequency that people like to talk about, and some of the evidence used to support the idea seemed a little irrelevant. Like, of course the sun emits 528 Hz light (as well as like the whole visible spectrum and out both sides). Is there something else about the sun that is 528 Hz specifically?

Do bees really buzz at 528 Hz? Obviously wing length would be a factor in deciding how fast they buzz.

Does the golden ratio have any discernable relation to 528 Hz? The golden ratio does appear in nature, so a connection there would certainly have some weight.

Are there any studies on harmonics within cellular structure at all, let alone determining that 528 Hz has anything to do with it?

These are some examples of what I'm looking for. Not random coincidences or things that naturally include 528, but specific things that require exactly 528 to operate properly or tend to be normally around 528 (in the bell curve at least).

Comment: What you have been reading is pure numerological **woo**. BTW, 528 Hz electromagnetic radiation is at the low end of ultra low frequency radio waves.

Comment: @David Hammen, 528 HZ is the frequency of bright green light, according to the Wikipedia article on the visible light spectrum, so it's not surprising they connect that to chlorophyl, but is that the actual color of chlorophyl? Also, if it is the actual color, doesn't that mean that it's reflecting that color and so would be the least affected by it (which sort of defeats the claim)? Just thinking out loud here. I recall seeing LED grow lights that are red and blue.

Comment: Oops, that's actually TeraHertz. Probably an important distinction, if you ask me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum

Comment: @ArlenBecter Terahertz vs hertz is a rather important distinction.

Comment: BTW, it's terahertz as opposed to teraHertz, hertz as opposed to Hertz. Having ones name lowercased (typically done posthumously) as the name of a unit is a huge honor in physics. So it's newtons rather than Newtons, volts rather than Volts, amperes rather than Amperes, kelvins rather than Kelvins, etc. The only exception is that degrees Celsius are spelled with an uppercase C.

Comment: this is just a frequenzy in the mid range of the human voice nothing special .and it is in no way related to earthscience,i vote to close this question as opinion based.

Comment: bees flap their wings 200 times a sec so 200hz with harmonics at 100-400-600-800 hz and so on